# Access O365 crashes while filling Excel with automation / VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Since a few days (last Office 365 / 2016 update) my Access application crashes spontaneously while filling in an Excel sheet.
The crash happens also in Debug, spontaneous without any error. It looks like it happens when trying to enter a value in a range-object (cell), but no clue..

Eventlog (sorry, Dutch):

> Naam van toepassing met fout: MSACCESS.EXE, versie: 16.0.12827.20336,
>   tijdstempel: 0x5edad85e Naam van module met fout: VBE7.DLL, versie:
>   0.0.0.0, tijdstempel: 0x5ea725ac Uitzonderingscode: 0xc0000005 Foutmarge: 0x0012a27f Id van proces met fout: 0x3940 Starttijd van
>   toepassing met fout: 0x01d63f55c6f18f41 Pad naar toepassing met fout:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE Pad
>   naar module met fout: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL Rapport-id:
>   beade252-a201-43dc-8afc-679995e130c1 Volledige pakketnaam met fout: 
>   Relatieve toepassings-id van pakket met fout:

Anyone experiencing VBA-issues since last update?

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be that you have been hit by a recent bug:

[Access VBA/DAO code may crash or report incorrect data for Decimal columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-vba-dao-code-may-crash-or-report-incorrect-data-for-decimal-columns-9311f0ab-ac34-40b4-abd7-2aaa01e07fc7)

If so, notice the included link for a temporary work-around.

Comment: I have seen this page, but I'm not sure this is the case. The symptoms however sound very similar, and I dó use DAO.. Could it be it also concerns other data types?

Comment: Can't tell, as I haven't met it myself. But many errors have been reported since the last update.